# ¿Al intentar subir mi proyecto laravel en .zip el file manager del cpanel este inmediatamente desaparece?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

Bueno la cuestión es que al intentar subir mi proyecto el cual lo comprimí en un archivo .zip simplemente desaparece al instante en que termina la carga de subida, no se si a alguien ya le sucedió lo mismos, esto lo intente es dos diferentes hosting y mediante ftp y ocurre lo mismo. Dé igual manera intente con otro proyecto que ya había subido pero ocurre lo mismo, la verdad no se lo que sucede.

Comment: Mi recomendación es realizar un deploy, guardar tu proyecto en github repositorio privado, tener acceso al hosting de preferencia VPS por ssh y realizar el deploy en cuestión de segundos a minutos tu proyecto esta listo, muchas veces tratar de descomprimir el archivo no funciona.

Comment: Será que se cree que es un virus y lo elimina cuando ya lo has subido y reconocido, o lo estas subiendo a una carpeta que luego no sabes encontrar

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, lo que me funciona fue subirlo mediante github, luego en otro hosting pude subir el archivo .zip pero luego no me dejaba descomprimirlo, por lo que use un archivo php llamado unzipper, descomprimir el archivo del proyecto desde el navegador accediendo al archivo en cuestión y con eso quedo solucionado el problema, lo comento por si ha alguien le sucede lo mismo. Les dejo el archivo que use: https://github.com/ndeet/unzipper.